# Determine a basis for $\operatorname{Im}f$ and $\operatorname{Ker}f$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B=(\underline{e_1}, \underline{e_2}, \underline{e_3}, \underline{e_4})$ a basis for a vector space $V$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Given the map
$$
f:V\longrightarrow V,\qquad f(\underline x)=-\underline x,
$$
determine a basis for $\operatorname{Im}f$ and $\operatorname{Ker}f$.

**My attempt.** I compute the matrix associated with $f$ and it easily results that
$$
M^{B, B}(f)=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So, a basis for $\operatorname{span}((-1, 0, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 0, 0, -1))$ is $((-1, 0, 0, 0), (0, -1, 0, 0), (0, 0, -1, 0), (0, 0, 0, -1))$ and hence a basis for $\operatorname{Im}f$ is 
$$
B_{\operatorname{Im}f}=(-\underline e_1, -\underline e_2, -\underline e_3, -\underline e_4).
$$
For the kernel, it easily results that $\operatorname{Ker}f=\{0\}$. Is my attempt correct?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. Also you could see that since $f$ is an automorphism a basis for $Im(f)$ is the normal $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\text{im} \;f = V$, and $\dim \text{im}\; f + \dim\text{ker} \; f = \dim V = 4$. So indeed $\dim \text{ker} \; f = 0$, which means $\ker \; f = \{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, I note that. Anyway, is it correct the attempt to compute the basis for $\operatorname{Im}f$? Thank You

Comment: Since $\text{im}\; f$ is simply equal to $V$, you can pick any basis of $V$ to be your basis for $\text{im} \; f$. Since $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ is a basis for $V$, so is $\{-e_1,-e_2,-e_3,-e_4\}$. So yes, your attempt is correct.